# How to catch Rewrite rules then display a specific post?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to catch the params sent by the rewrite rules and then display a selected post.

But for now, even if I can retrieve those param, the page redirect to the archive of my custom post type. Where I need to display the post that match a custom query build from the query string given by the rewrite rule.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    $terms_slug = getCustomTermsSlug();
    // @note Catch /{foo}
    add_rewrite_rule('^(' . implode('|', $terms_slug) . ')/?', 'index.php?post_type=custom&foo=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_tag('%foo%', '([^&]+)');
}, 10, 0);

add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if (get_query_var('foo')) {
        $tax_query = [[
            'taxonomy' => 'custom',
            'field' => 'slug',
            // @note "foo" is a custom taxonomy term
            'terms' => get_query_var('foo'),
        ]];

        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }

    return $query;
});
```

First, I don't understand why it redirect to the archive page?

Second, maybe the "pre_get_posts" is not the right place to make the customized query but where I can do it then?

Third, how to display the selected post in response of the clean URL given?

Thank's for your help! ;-)

@EDIT
I've tried using actions like "template_redirect" or "parse_request" but it feel really *hacky. Is anyone know how to force the redirect (eg. rewrite matching) to the first post of the custom query?

Comment: You've used term_sulg in one place

Comment: hello @birgire, the "term_slug" string is only an example... but what did you mean exactly?

Comment: You use `$args` but don't set it anywhere.

Comment: Oh ! That's a mistake when writing the question... I fix that right now! ;-)

Comment: @MonkeyMonk I meant the term_sulg typo (should be term_slug) Maybe that's just in this example and alright in your code?

Comment: @birgire I've renamed "term_slug" to "foo", is it less confusing as it? And yes, the whole thing works as expected until the post selection. I think I have to manually do the query to select the right post to display under the rewrited URL... but don't know how and where to do it.

Comment: It's difficult and sometimes impossible to convert one type of request to another in pre_get_posts. You need to hook before query parsing if you are doing anything major, or you need to set the correct query vars in your rule to let wp know you intend this to be a single post view rather than archive.

Answer (score 1):

It appear, like @milo also said, that the correct way to doing this is by using the "parse_request" action that stand before the "pre_get_posts" action (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

The complete solution I came with :

```
add_action('init', function () {
    $refs_slug = getCustomRefTermsSlug(); // this will return an array of all the terms slug existing in the custom "ref" taxonomy

    // @note Catch /{foo|bar|baz} and redirect to index.php?catch_me=true?ref={foo|bar|baz}
    add_rewrite_rule('^(' . implode('|', $refs_slug) . ')/?', 'index.php?post_type=custom&catch_me=true&ref=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_tag('%ref%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%catch_me%', '([^&]+)');
}, 10, 0);

add_action('parse_request', function ($query) {
    if (array_key_exists('catch_me', $query->query_vars) && $query->query_vars['catch_me']) {
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'custom',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'tax_query' => [],
        ];

        if (array_key_exists('ref', $query->query_vars)) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = [
                'taxonomy' => 'ref',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $query->query_vars['ref'],
            ];
        }

        // get the right post
        $tmp_query = new \WP_Query($args);
        $post_id = $tmp_query->posts[0];

        // tell wordpress what post to display
        $query->query_vars = [
            'post_type' => 'custom',
            'p' => $post_id,
        ];
    }

    return $query;
});

add_filter('post_type_link', function ($url, $post) {
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'custom') {
        $refs_slug = getCustomRefTermsSlug($post->ID); // this will return an array of all the terms slug of the custom "ref" taxonomy assigned to the post

        // @note Return "/{foo|bar|bar}" as the permalink of the post
        return '/' . implode('/', $refs_slug);
    }

    return $url;
}, 10, 2);
```

Feel free to give me comments! ;-)